# How to make react-native-voice module keep listening in Android?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-voice

I am not sure if these are the correct behaviours or not but the events work a bit different in iOS and Android.
In Android the `react-native-voice` module stop listening to voice after calling the following methods

```
Voice.android.js:70 onSpeechPartialResults {value: Array(1)}
Voice.android.js:70 onSpeechPartialResults {value: Array(1)}
Voice.android.js:70 onSpeechPartialResults {value: Array(1)}
Voice.android.js:70 onSpeechPartialResults {value: Array(1)}
Voice.android.js:74 onSpeechEnd {error: false}
Voice.android.js:78 onSpeechResults {value: Array(5)}
```

Is it possible to make the module listening without making it stop?

Tested Android versions: 9.0.5, 8.0